# Skip numbers that include certain number in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a function which takes 3 parameters – start, end and bannedNumber.  It should print all the numbers from start to end but skip all multiples of the banned number and any number that has a banned number in it.

Here is my code:

```
 <script>
  var arr = [];
  var str = "";
  var newarr = [];
  var str1
  function Zumbaniaa(a, b, c) {
    for (var i = a; i < b; i++) {
      arr.push(i);
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (arr[j] % c == 0) {
        arr.splice(j, 1);
      }
    }

    for (var m = 0; m < arr.length; m++) {
      str = arr[m].toString();
      str1=str.split("");
      if (str1.indexOf(c) >=0) {
        arr.splice(m, 1);
      }
    }
    return arr
  }


  document.write(Zumbaniaa(1, 90, 8))
  console.log(str1)
</script>
```

For some reason the third loop is not working. It's not filtering numbers with 8 at all.

Comment: Variable names like `a`, `b`, `c`, `arr`, `str`, `str1`, `newarr` and `Zumbaniaa` tell me nothing about how this program is supposed to work or what any of this data is. I recommend writing descriptive variable names and showing expected/actual input/output. Is there a reason why all of the function's state data is initialized globally? This breaks encapsulation and makes the function non-idempotent without apparent reason. Thanks.

Comment: Also, calling `splice` on a list while forward iterating it is going to result in skipped indices because `arr.length` changes as a result of the `splice` call, throwing `i` off by one on each call. Iterate backwards if you plan to use `splice` in a loop. Better yet, use `Array#filter` for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simplest to just not push the banned values into the array to begin with. So check if the numbers to be pushed are a multiple of the banned digit, or contain the banned digit before you push:

```js
function filtered_range(start, end, banned) {
  let nums = [];
  for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    if (i % banned != 0 && i.toString().indexOf(banned) == -1) nums.push(i);
  }
  return nums;
}
console.log(filtered_range(1, 90, 8).join(' '));
```

Comment: @Nick you could reduce this even further with an `Array.from(Array(90).keys()).filter()` function

Comment: @symlink you're right (although that would give an array from 0 to 89 not 1 to 90 and doesn't allow for a `start` variable, still could easily be modified to deal with that) - but based on the code in the question I wanted to keep the answer as vanilla as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line: `str1 = str.split("");`. It is causing `indexOf()` to fail. Call `str.indexOf(c)` instead. Then reverse the final loop.

What is happening: `indexOf()` works on strings and arrays. When used on a string, the character being searched for is always parsed first to a string, because strings only contain strings. When used on an array, the character being searched for isn't parsed at all, because arrays can contain strings, numbers, etc.

```js
var arr = [];
var str = "";
var newarr = [];
var str1

function Zumbaniaa(a, b, c) {
  for (var i = a; i < b; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
  }

  for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    if (arr[j] % c == 0) {
      arr.splice(j, 1);
    }
  }


  for (var m = arr.length - 1; m > 0; m--) {
    str = arr[m].toString();
    //str1 = str.split("");

    if (str.indexOf(c) >= 0) {
      arr.splice(m, 1);
    }
  }
  return arr
}

Zumbaniaa(1, 90, 8);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Hi, but in this way 82,84,86,89 are still printed?